# In React Native, why isn't my icon right aligned?

Tags: react-native, native

I'm using React Native with NativeBase as follows:

https://snack.expo.io/@deltanovember/tab-swipe

I'm trying to implement the Advanced Deck Swiper here:

http://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#deckswiper-adv-headref

My code is almost identical as the example, but my forward icon is aligned on the left of the button:

[image]

whereas based on the example, it should be aligned to the right of the button:

[image]

How do I make the alignment match the example (ie icon on the right of the button?)

Comment: <Text> first and then <Icon> should work for the right button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this issue is because you did not set style for your `<Body />` tag

This should work correctly

and try work with styles when see this in where ever in your project

this is your right button:

```
      <Button
        iconRight
        onPress={() => this._deckSwiper._root.swipeRight()}>
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row-reverse' }} >
          <Icon name="ios-arrow-forward" />
          <Text>Swipe Right</Text>
        </View>
      </Button>
```

Maybe just switching the icon and text will fix this but it's better to be regular :)

(Good luck this is my second answer to you my friend in day :DDDD )

Answer (score 1):

You're placing icon and text in uncorrect order. I just switched them and it works:

```
    <Text>Swipe Right</Text>
    <Icon name="ios-arrow-forward" />
```